# Why servletContext method getRealPath return path to target dir?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, realpath

I have simple project structure

[image]

And I have servlet that show realpath to WEB-INF dir

```
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        System.out.println(context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF"));
    }


}
```

When I run this application console shows

[image]

How can I get path to Web-inf dir but not for target?I want store user image there

Comment: That is the real path - your application is compiled and packaged then run from `target`. Your application has no conception of Maven and it’s folder structure.

Comment: @Boris the Spider, So If  I restart the server won't it be removed?